# How can I calculate the distance of a state within a cluster from the center of the cluster?

Tags: r, database, plot, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing

I have a sample of 28 states.
I want to plot them in one cluster, identify the center, and then calculate the distance of every state from the center, per year.

my input file resemble the following:
first column: Country
second column: Year  (from 2008 to 2017)
third column: PI (index)

Question 1:
I am getting the error:
Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'mydata.year' not found
when I run:
table_2008 = subset(table1, mydata.year ==2008)

Question 2:
Which code is best suited to calculate the distance of a state from the center of the cluster.

Please find my code below.
I hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Code:

heisenberg <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/TA/Desktop/R4./PI4.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
rm(list=ls())

```
mydata = read.csv("C:/Users/TA/Desktop/R4./PI4.csv",sep = ",", header=TRUE)

mydata$Country
mydata$Category
mydata$PI

data_cluster = data.frame(mydata$Country,mydata$Category,mydata$PI)

write.csv(data_cluster,"C:/Users/TA/Desktop/R4./OutputPI.csv", row.names = FALSE)


table1 = data_cluster



#plot(uk_line[,4])
table1 = na.omit(table1)

within_results = ts(,start = c(2008), end = c(2017), frequency = 1)
within_resultsbetweenss = ts(,start = c(2008), end = c(2017), frequency = 1)
within_results_withinss = matrix(data= NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 4) 
#nrow = years, ncols = number of clusters

#colnames(mydata, c("Country","Year"))

#YEAR 2008
#SELECTING A GIVEN YEAR (subset of rows such that year = 2008)
table_2008 = subset(table1, mydata.year ==2008)
table_2008


data2008_clus = table_2008[,3:ncol(table_2008)]

#NAMING THE ROWS USING THE COUNTRY NAMES
rownames(data2008_clus) = table_2008$mydata.Country

data2008_clus


plot(table_2008)

wss <- (nrow(data2008_clus)-1)*sum(apply(data2008_clus,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data2008_clus,
                                     centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares")




# Compute k-means with k = 1


fit1=kmeans(x = data2008_clus,centers = 1)
fit1$cluster
fviz_cluster(fit1,data = data2008_clus)
fit1$withinss
fit1$totss
fit1$betweenss
table_2008$cluster = factor(fit1$cluster)
centers=as.data.frame(fit1$centers)
table_2008

within_results[1] = fit1$totss
within_resultsbetweenss[1] = fit1$betweenss
within_results_withinss[1,] = fit1$withinss
within_results_withinss[1,] =  fit1$withinss

plot(within_results)
plot(within_resultsbetweenss)
plot(within_results_withinss)

# Print the results 
print(km.res)
table_2008
```

mydata_struct = structure(
list(
Year = c(2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L),
Country = structure(
1:6,
.Label = c(
"Austria",
"Belgium",
"Bulgaria",
"Croatia",
"Cyprus",
"Czechia",
"Denmark",
"Estonia",
"Finland",
"France",
"Germany",
"Greece",
"Hungary",
"Ireland",
"Italy",
"Latvia",
"Lithuania",
"Luxembourg",
"Malta",
"Netherlands",
"Poland",
"Portugal",
"Romania",
"Slovakia",
"Slovenia",
"Spain",
"Sweden",
"United Kingdom"
),
class = "factor"
),
Prosperity.Index = c(79.4,
76.1, 62, 65.1, 69.9, 70.9)
),
row.names = c(NA, 6L),
class = "data.frame"
)

Comment: What is `mydata.year`? Do you mean `mydata$year` ? Clustering with one cluster means that the centroid of the cluster is the means for all the variables you are using. To get distances, just create a data frame with the variables centered (see ?scale). Sum the squared values and take the square root.

Comment: thank you @dcarlson. Do I need to add a dummy variable? My data set contains only one variable, the aggregate index Prosperity Index. I want to calculate the dispersion for the 28-state per year. So I only have the state and the PI for that state for a specific year. Thank you.

Comment: Provide some sample data using `dput()`. If you have 1 variable and 1 cluster, the distance is the absolute value of the difference between each value and the mean of all values.

Comment: thank you @dcarlson. So I need to calculate the dispersion of EU-28 member states for every year (2008-2017), based on the prosperity index data. So yes I have 1 variable and 1 cluster for every year. I want to to visualize on a graph the cluster of 28 states, with the center, and I want to calculate the distance to that center. So other than the graph I want a numeric value generated by R accounting for the distance.  I am sharing my data for 2008.

Comment: mydata_struct = structure(
  list(
    Year = c(
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2008L,
      2009L
    ),
    Country = structure(
      c(
        1L,
        2L,
        3L,
        4L,

Comment: 5L,
        6L,
        7L,
        8L,
        9L,
        10L,
        11L,
        12L,
        13L,
        14L,
        15L,
        16L,
        17L,
        18L,
        19L,
        20L,
        21L,
        22L,
        23L,
        24L,
        25L,
        26L,
        27L,
        28L,
        1L
      ),
      .Label = c(
        "Austria",
        "Belgium",
        "Bulgaria",
        "Croatia",
        "Cyprus",

Comment: "Czechia",
        "Denmark",
        "Estonia",
        "Finland",
        "France",
        "Germany",
        "Greece",
        "Hungary",
        "Ireland",
        "Italy",
        "Latvia",
        "Lithuania",
        "Luxembourg",

Comment: "Malta",
        "Netherlands",
        "Poland",
        "Portugal",
        "Romania",
        "Slovakia",
        "Slovenia",
        "Spain",
        "Sweden",
        "United Kingdom"
      ),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    Prosperity.Index = c(
      79.4,
      76.1,
      62,
      65.1,

Comment: 69.9,
      70.9,
      83.2,
      73.5,
      81.2,
      75.9,
      79.9,
      66,
      66.7,
      78.9,
      69.6,
      67.7,
      66.6,
      79.9,
      73.4,
      81.2,
      66.9,
      71,
      62.6,
      68.2,
      72.7,
      72.6,
      82.8,
      78,
      79.4
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 29L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

Comment: Add this to your original question, not as a series of comments. You provided all the country data for one year. We really need 4 - 5 countries for 4 - 5 years. Use `subset` to produce a reduced version of the data and post it by editing your original question. There are many measures of "dispersion". Which do you want?

Comment: I've just posted a possible answer. See if this is close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can generate random values for the rest of the years. You do not need to do this since your data is complete. I'm just trying to create data that resembles yours:

```
mydata_struct = structure( list( Year = c( 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L,
     2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L,
     2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L ),
     Country = structure( c( 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,
     15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L ),
     .Label = c( "Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark",
     "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy",
     "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal",
     "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom" ),
     class = "factor" ), Prosperity.Index = c( 79.4, 76.1, 62, 65.1, 69.9, 70.9, 83.2, 73.5,
     81.2, 75.9, 79.9, 66, 66.7, 78.9, 69.6, 67.7, 66.6, 79.9, 73.4, 81.2, 66.9, 71, 62.6,
     68.2, 72.7, 72.6, 82.8, 78, 79.4 ) ), row.names = c(NA, 29L), class = "data.frame" )
```

Now we create data for the other years and a data frame `Prosperity` by copying the data for the first year:

```
names <- rep(mydata_struct$Country[1:28], 10)
years <- rep(2008:2017, each=28)
prosp <- rep(mydata_struct$Prosperity.Index[1:28], 10)
Prosperity <- data.frame(Country=names, Year=years, PI=prosp)
```

Now we will fuzz the other years and add a trend toward increasing prosperity:

```
set.seed(42)
Prosperity$PI <- rnorm(280, prosp, rnorm(280, 2, .25)) + (years - years[1]) * rnorm(280, 1, .25)
```

Here is where you start with your actual data. First we can get some statistics:

```
options(digits=4)
with(Prosperity, tapply(PI, Year, mean))   # Mean PI for each year
#  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017 
# 73.02 73.74 74.50 76.50 76.13 77.95 78.33 79.55 80.85 81.71 
with(Prosperity, tapply(PI, Year, sd))     # Standard deviation for PI for each year
#  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017 
# 6.861 6.422 6.840 6.935 6.582 6.592 8.331 6.777 7.489 8.044 
with(Prosperity, tapply(PI, Year, max) - tapply(PI, Year, min))  # Range in PI for each year
#  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017 
# 28.24 23.24 22.20 24.83 23.99 23.26 27.97 22.77 27.78 30.66
```

Finally some plots:

```
plot(PI~Year, Prosperity)   # Plot all values
boxplot(PI~Year, Prosperity)   # Boxplots
```

[image: Scatterplot]

[image: Boxplots]