# How can I calculate the distance of a state within a cluster from the center of the cluster and visualize it on a graph?

Tags: r, database, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing

I have a sample of 28 states. I want to plot them in one cluster, identify the center, and then calculate the distance of every state from the center, per year.

my input file resemble the following: first column: Country second column: Year (from 2008 to 2017) third column: PI (index)

Question 1: I am getting the error:

> Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'mydata.year' not found when I run: table_2008 = subset(table1, mydata.year ==2008)

Question 2: Which code is best suited to calculate the distance of a state from the center of the cluster.

Initially, I designed four aggregate indices to analyse progress in EU member states (economic, political, social, and institutional). I then clustered the state 6 and visualized them as per the image below (k.means and ggplot). I was calculating the distance between clusters, and the distance between states within a cluster by using withinss and totss.

However, I decide to analyse the state from another perspective. Instead of redesigning an index, I decided to use the Prosperity Index (aggregate index including the four issue areas (economic, political, social, and institutional). Therefor I ended up with 1 variable. what I wish to do is consider that EU member states form one cluster - so I have one cluster of 28 states for every year 2008 to 2017), and I want to calculate the distance of every state to the center. I need a specific numeric value for every state for every year.

Lastly, I want to be able to visualize in a graph similar to the one in the image attached. I will have ten graphs for every year (2008 to 2017). Each graph will contain all 28 state with a center.

My code is:

```
mydata = read.csv("C:/Users/TA/Desktop/R4./PI4.csv",sep = ",", header=TRUE)

mydata$Country
mydata$Category
mydata$PI

data_cluster = data.frame(mydata$Country,mydata$Category,mydata$PI)

write.csv(data_cluster,"C:/Users/TA/Desktop/R4./OutputPI.csv", row.names = FALSE)


table1 = data_cluster



#plot(uk_line[,4])
table1 = na.omit(table1)

within_results = ts(,start = c(2008), end = c(2017), frequency = 1)
within_resultsbetweenss = ts(,start = c(2008), end = c(2017), frequency = 1)
within_results_withinss = matrix(data= NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 4) 
#nrow = years, ncols = number of clusters

#colnames(mydata, c("Country","Year"))

#YEAR 2008
#SELECTING A GIVEN YEAR (subset of rows such that year = 2008)
table_2008 = subset(table1, mydata.year ==2008)
table_2008


data2008_clus = table_2008[,3:ncol(table_2008)]

#NAMING THE ROWS USING THE COUNTRY NAMES
rownames(data2008_clus) = table_2008$mydata.Country

data2008_clus


plot(table_2008)

wss <- (nrow(data2008_clus)-1)*sum(apply(data2008_clus,2,var))
for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data2008_clus,
                                     centers=i)$withinss)
plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
     ylab="Within groups sum of squares")




# Compute k-means with k = 1


fit1=kmeans(x = data2008_clus,centers = 1)
fit1$cluster
fviz_cluster(fit1,data = data2008_clus)
fit1$withinss
fit1$totss
fit1$betweenss
table_2008$cluster = factor(fit1$cluster)
centers=as.data.frame(fit1$centers)
table_2008

within_results[1] = fit1$totss
within_resultsbetweenss[1] = fit1$betweenss
within_results_withinss[1,] = fit1$withinss
within_results_withinss[1,] =  fit1$withinss

plot(within_results)
plot(within_resultsbetweenss)
plot(within_results_withinss)

# Print the results 
print(km.res)
table_2008
```

As for my data set,

```
mydata_struct = structure( list( Year = c( 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L ), Country = structure( c( 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, –5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 1L ), .Label = c( "Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Croatia", "Cyprus", –"Czechia", "Denmark", "Estonia", "Finland", "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Italy", "Latvia", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", –"Malta", "Netherlands", "Poland", "Portugal", "Romania", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Spain", "Sweden", "United Kingdom" ), class = "factor" ), Prosperity.Index = c( 79.4, 76.1, 62, 65.1, – 69.9, 70.9, 83.2, 73.5, 81.2, 75.9, 79.9, 66, 66.7, 78.9, 69.6, 67.7, 66.6, 79.9, 73.4, 81.2, 66.9, 71, 62.6, 68.2, 72.7, 72.6, 82.8, 78, 79.4 ) ), row.names = c(NA, 29L), class = "data.frame" )
```

[image]

Comment: With one variable, you can only plot the distance of the countries along a line according to their distance from the center. A 2 dimensional plot like your example requires at least 2 dimensions, that is 2 variables. This is essentially the same question you asked earlier [How can I calculate the distance of a state within a cluster from the center of the cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63090969/how-can-i-calculate-the-distance-of-a-state-within-a-cluster-from-the-center-of).

Comment: Your data says `Year` but your subset statement (for 2008) says `year`.   R is case-sensitive.